# difference between webrtc::VideoFrame and webrtc::EncodedImage

Tags: c++, webrtc

The question is what is the difference between `webrtc::VideoFrame` and `webrtc::EncodedImage`. The purpose of the question is that I have `webrtc::EncoededImage` and I need to send it to another peer. But I can't find any way to do that in `cricket::VideoCapturer`. But there is onFrame method. As I understand it was made to send that frame. So I just thought that if I could convert`webrtc::EncodedImage` to `webrtc::VideoFrame` I could send that image to another peer. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you have an encoded frame, you need to push it down to the packetizer.

filters:

Capturer => Encoder => RTP Packetizer => Encryption => Transport

Data types:

1. **Capturer**    => Video Frame
2. Video   Frame => **Encoder**     => Encoded Frame
3. Encoded Frame => **RTP Packet.** => RTP Packet(s)
4. RTP Packet    => **Encryption**  => SRTP packet
5. SRTP Packet   => **Transport**   => UDP or TCP packet

Comment: Can you tell me which classes and methods I should use to do that?